# UIViews display at wrong location in landscape mode

Tags: ipad, uiview, positioning, landscape

I am working on an diagramming application which displays boxes as subviews inside a larger view. The user can move the boxes around. I am persisting the positions of these boxes using core data into a sqlite database by holding the height, width, x and y (of the top-left corner). When I open up a diagram I am reading these values from the database and using them to set the frame of the subview within the main view.

In portrait mode this works fine and the boxes are repositioned at the correct points on the display. However, when I rotate into landscape, or start the application in landscape and open the diagram, the positions of the boxes are wrong.

I have traced through the code and can see that the correct values are coming back from the persistent store and being used to correctly set the frame. However, once the UIView for the subview is on screen it is positioned at a different location (clearly visible and confirmed by checking the values in the frame of the view).

Now the odd thing is that instead of being a fixed pixel offset, the x co-ordinate is always 8.5% larger than the value used to create the frame, and the y value is always 9.1% smaller.

Does anyone have any explanation as to why this might be and how I might solve the problem?

If it provides any clues, the main view is inside a UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the answer. I needed to set Autoresize Subviews to false on the UIScrollView. Having done that (by un-checking the appropriate box in IB) everything seems to be working fine.